# execute github project after cloning

Tags: github, fpdf

I downloaded a project from GitHub in this link [Fpdf GitHub project](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf)
and I'm trying to execute it in the browser. I followed the instructions:

```
   git clone https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf.git
   cd pyfpdf
   python setup.py install
```

Directory looks like this, no file with extension `.sh`, so how can I run this project?
[image]

How can I execute this project, any help?

Comment: What do you mean by executing? It is a library to be used in applications.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen There're some examples there, I thought that I can execute them? I'm new on  this, maybe I'm  making an inappropriate question, sorry about this!